# C#: ASP.NET Web-Messenger (Chat)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, chat

i programmed a Chat-Program like ICQ with C# and WCF.

Now i want to build a Web-Client-Version with ASP.NET.
Is this possible? I want that new chatrooms-popup in the window like meebo (or in a new tab).
I have to use the Client-WebService-Class from my WCF-service, right? But is it possible to react on server-side Events with ASP.NET?
New messages, new chatroom-invitations, chat events like "user goes online/offline" should be handled dynamically by the site without refresh-actions from the user.

Are there some tutorials?

Comment: I too would like some insite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything in the current technology that allows a server to refresh a browser client.  So you're not going to get something that's server-initiated to update the client (unless you're using [Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94826/Silverlight-Notification-Messages-from-the-Server.aspx)).

Most answers to this question have suggested that you regularly poll your server for any changes to the conversation and update the output in javascript.  Here's one from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/AliAspNetChat.aspx).  Googling for ASP.NET chat or MVC Chat produces similar results.